# JSON não aparece quando faço a requsição

Tags: php, api, restful, slimframework

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em PHP com Slim Framework, porém quando eu requisito a classe *geral* ele devia fazer uma consulta no banco de dados e me retornar os dados dessa tabela em JSON.

Essa é a classe de conexão com o banco de dados

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$bd_nome = "liceuapp";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd_nome);
```

Essa é a classe que faz a consulta no banco de dados e deveria me retornar o JSON dessa tabela

```
<?php
$app->get('/comunicados/geral', function() {

    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    $query = "select * from geral";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;

    }
    if (isset($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
});
```

Porém, quando eu chamo a URL api/comunicados/**geral** a tela fica branca, não exibe o JSON da tabela solicitada.

Me ajudem, por favor!

Comment: "A tela fica branca" pode significar que rolou algum erro. Já conferiu os logs? Realmente tem registros nessa tabela (vai que)? O PHP tá configurado pra exibir os erros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caio, talvez você precise descobrir primeiro onde ocorre o erro, tente incluir um echo em cada linha para ver até em que ponto sua aplicação chega.